# Mono.Android.dll not support in .Net Maui, Any alternative for Android.Telephony?

Tags: maui

I'm trying to create sms app in .net maui using Android.Telephony. I was successfully done it during debug. In release mode, although it return errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3wtJ.png), it let me finished the app install to my device and it works fine too. but when I try to publish (create archive or an apk). its always failed to published. I believe its the Android.Telephony cause the failures. Any Suggestion or any alternative to Android.Telephony in .net maui? Thank you

Comment: “Failed to publish” - what does this mean?  Do you get an error?  When something works in Debug but not Release that often points to a Linker problem

Comment: Why does the question title refer to `Mono.Android.dll`? That isn't in the question body itself, nor in the errors image you have. Also, please add to question **as text that can be searched** (rather than as an image) all relevant error messages. Also add all lines related to `Android.Telephony`, either in `.csproj` (perhaps Nuget package references?), or in `AppManifest.xml`.

Comment: Hmm. Its unclear to me how this worked in Debug, **on Android,** given that Maui targets .Net 6 or 7, and [Android.Telephony](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.telephony?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13&viewFallbackFrom=net-7.0) is supported by Xamarin, on earlier .Nets, but according to the docs, not supported by .Net 6 or 7. Did you Debug on Android emulator, or was your Debug target "Windows Machine"?

Comment: When I used the SmsManager in the maui project, it will use the `Android.Telephony` namespace. This error message shouldn't appear.